# PHP to MySql Form process multiple select checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I don't know how to structure the PHP/MySQL queries to accomplish this. I am trying to add items to a list. I have a form which lists all items with a multiple checkbox form. For every item checked, I need it to create a new entry into a MYSQL table. The table is has three fields, entry_id, list_id and item_id.

So that, if I displayed a list of 5 items

LIST #1

- Item 1
- Item 2
- Item 3
- Item 4
- Item 5

And selected 3

LIST #1

- Item 1
- Item 2*
- Item 3*
- Item 4
- Item 5*

I need the php/mysql code which will insert those values into the table like so:

- entry_id   /  list_id  /   item_id
- 1      /      1     /      2
- 2      /      1     /      3
- 3      /      1     /      5

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it:

```
<?php
  // get array of selected elements
  $selections = $_POST['selections'];
  $list = intval($_POST['list_id'], 10);
  // prevent sql injection
  $selections = array_map(function ($el) {
    return intval($el, 10);
  }, $selections);
  // create tuples
  $selections = array_map(function ($el) use ($list) {
    return '(' . $list . ', ' . $el . ')';
  }, $selections);
  // create a comma sperated list of tuples
  $selections = implode(', ', $selections);
  $sql = 'INSERT INTO table (list_id, item_id) VALUES ' . $selections . ';';

  // run $sql through the driver of your choice
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use HTML like the following:

```
<strong>List Number 1</strong>
<ul>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" name="checked[1][]" value="1">Value 1</label></li>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" name="checked[1][]" value="2">Value 2</label></li>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" name="checked[1][]" value="3">Value 3</label></li>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" name="checked[1][]" value="4">Value 4</label></li>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" name="checked[1][]" value="5">Value 5</label></li>
</ul>

<strong>List Number 2</strong>
<ul>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" name="checked[2][]" value="1">Value 1</label></li>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" name="checked[2][]" value="2">Value 2</label></li>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" name="checked[2][]" value="3">Value 3</label></li>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" name="checked[2][]" value="4">Value 4</label></li>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" name="checked[2][]" value="5">Value 5</label></li>
</ul>
```

Where the `name` parameter has a format of `checked[X][]` where "X" is the List ID.

On submission, with the values mentioned in your question, you would get:

```
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "2"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "3"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "5"
  }
}
```

So to produce an array like that which you have mentioned in the OP:

```
$sqlValues = array();
foreach( $_POST['checked'] as $list_id => $values ){
  foreach( $values as $k => $v ){
    $sqlValues[] = ( $k+1 ).' , '.(int) $list_id.' , ' .(int) $v;
  }
}
$sqlCmd = 'INSERT INTO `yourTable` ( `entry_id` , `list_id` , `item_id` )
           VALUES ( '.implode( ' ) , ( ' , $sqlValues ).' )';
```